# how send data to server via xml using php

Tags: php, xml

i get data in xml from a form in php,
the problem is how i send this data to server via xml using php,
i thing this is very basic,but i am totally new to xml,
kindly help me thanks in advance to every one

Comment: Are you trying to send serialized data to some PHP handler script, or are you trying to upload XML content that needs to written to a file somewhere?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Please include specifics and code if possible so we can help you more easily.

Comment: hi Tieson T.,
thanks for the rply,
actually i have a form from which i want to send data to database through xml,
without writing it to a file

Answer (score 0):

You don't "send" information to a database. You connect to it using mysql_connect() and then use SQL commands to insert the info into the database. If this is a remote server then you can use CURL to send the information, but I don't see why that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax to deal with this problem.